# rdlc report image not showing when using azure blob storage

Tags: image, azure, rdlc

I am converting an application from my own hosted server to Azure Websites. I use RDLC to create reports, invoices, etc. I use fixed URL's to load images with

(IE:  logo = String.Format("file:///{0}{1}", path, "logo" & XXXXXX & ".jpg")

The variable logo is passed via report parameters into the RDLC.

This works fine when my programs run on my on server. HOWEVER, when I use my Azure Storage container URL, the image does not get loaded when my report runs.

When I use a URL from my web site, the image loads properly.

This works:    logo = "http://www.resellsolutions.com/images/ReSell-191x72.png"

This does not work:

logo = "http://crmna.blob.core.windows.net/logos/2d66e0fb-d534-434f-9a81-d3f02256e25f_ReSell-191x72.png"

I can load the blob storage URL into a web browser and the image loads fine. It just will not load in the report.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: When I click on the blob storage link, I get a 404 error. Can you please check if the blob is still there?

Comment: it is still there - I just clicked on the link and the image was displayed.

Comment: I'm still not able to see it. Is it possible that your browser has cached the image? Can you try it with other browser (or by deleting the cache in your browser). I tried from 2 different systems and in both I got 404 error.

Comment: Gaurav - sorry - I was playing around with the length of the url and shorted the name - try this url please: "http://crmna.blob.core.windows.net/logos/ReSell-191x72.png"  you will have to add the "http://" manually. The editor is not adding it in the comments.

Comment: Here is another thought. the URL that works has a "www" in it. adding a "www" in the blob storage URL does not work in a browser. I wonder if a RDLC report needs "www" when using a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why you're running into this issue. I accessed the image through Fiddler and this is the response I got:

[image]

If not notice, `content-type` of the blob is set as `application/octet-stream` and this is causing the problem. Please change the content-type property of the blob to `image/png` and that should fix the problem.

Comment: I change the content-type to "image/png". please see if this resolves the issue through the browser.

Comment: Actually I just listed blobs in your blob container and this blob does not even exist in that container. Can you please make sure that the blob exists in the container.

Comment: good - I appreciate the help! Now I have another issue. It seems Azure does not support RDLC reports! This means I have 100's of reports to do something else with! So how are we supposed to create invoices, etc?